# Each http request takes 60 seconds Why?

Tags: c#, .net, http, tcp, networkstream

Below is the code block illustrating how I can send an HTTP request using TCP and network stream. However, regardless of any filtering applied, each request consistently consumes an average of 60 seconds. Whether a single data or a thousand arrive, the delay remains constant. Why does it persist at 60 seconds? Is there no option to shorten this period or a setting to fetch data immediately without waiting?

```
// Specify the server and port
string server = "xxx.com";
int port = 80;

// Specify the HTTP request
string httpRequest = "POST /ApiPrefixNameHere/ControllerNameHere/ActionNameHere HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: xxx.com\r\naccept: text/plain\r\nContent-Type: application/json-patch+json\r\nContent-Length: 27\r\n\r\n{\"ParameterNameHere\":\"1580\"}";

// Create a TcpClient
using (TcpClient tcpClient = new())
{
    await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(server, port);

    using (NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new(networkStream, Encoding.ASCII))
    using (StreamReader reader = new(networkStream, Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        // Send the HTTP request
        await writer.WriteAsync(httpRequest);
        await writer.FlushAsync();

        // Read the response
        string response = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        // Display the response
        Console.WriteLine("Response: " + response);
    }
}
```

I'm not well-versed in these older methods. I attempted strategies like NoDelay() and various timeout configurations, but none proved effective.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

---

EDIT after @jonskeet's answer

```
// add `Connection: close`
string httpRequest = "POST /ApiPrefixNameHere/ControllerNameHere/ActionNameHere HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: xxx.com\r\naccept: text/plain\r\nContent-Type: application/json-patch+json\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Length: 28\r\n\r\n{\"ParameterNameHere\":\"1580\"}";
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're making the request using TCP directly rather than using HttpClient? How long does the request take if you use HttpClient or just a browser? (Fundamentally, if the request is taking 60 seconds at the *server* then there's not a lot we can say...)

Comment: Aside from anything else, it's odd that you've specified a content length of 27 but then written 28 bytes. Perhaps that's part of the problem? (Additionally, you might want to specify `Connection: close` as a header - it looks like you're expecting the server to close the connection after the request, but that's not the default for HTTP/1.1.)

Comment: Both of these errors are examples of why it would be better to use a higher-level class such as `HttpClient` instead of `TcpClient`...

Comment: If *anything* takes a suspiciously even amount of time, there is a decent chance there is some timeout somewhere. And timeouts may not necessarily result in failure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can see two problems with the specific code you've got, but more generally I'd *strongly* encourage you not to use `TcpClient` for HTTP requests unless you *absolutely have to*. Both of these problems would have been avoided if you'd used `HttpClient`, I believe.

Firstly, you're specifying a header of `Content-Length: 27` - but then you're sending 28 bytes of content, as far as I can see. Maybe that's only a problem in the sample code, but it does demonstrate how brittle this approach is.

Secondly, you're calling `StreamReader.ReadToEnd`, which means you're waiting for the connection to be closed. You're not closing the connection, which means you're expecting the server to close it. But in HTTP/1.1 (which is the version you're specifying), the default behavior is to keep the connection alive. So I strongly suspect that what you're seeing is the server immediately send a response - and then time out after a minute waiting for the next request.

To avoid this, you can send a header of `Connection: close`... or preferably, use `HttpClient` so you don't need to know details of HTTP.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Adding `connection: close` solved my problem. By the way, I knew the Content-Length must be 28. This httpRequest string is a dummy. Also, I know using HttpClient or IHttpClientFactory is better than this. But I had to do this. It was said that everything would be generic for business reasons. I tried to use curl. Then it turned into this. I'm not sure if I'll use this or not anyway.